# How can I tried to render forms to this MainScreen.js file when the user click on in the navbar?

Tags: reactjs

The main form page where the login and Sign up form will live give undefined. How can I tried to render forms to this `MainScreen.js` file when the user click on in the navbar.

1. MainScreen.js (Where the forms are live)

```js
import React from 'react';
import RegisterBox from '../Forms/Register'
import LoginBox from '../Forms/Login'
    
    
    // This is the page for form to live on
    class App extends React.Component {
    
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isLoginOpen: true,
          isRegisterOpen: false
        };
      }
    
        render() {
            return (
              <div>
                <div className="root-container">
                    {this.state.isLoginOpen && <LoginBox/>}
                    {this.state.isRegisterOpen && <RegisterBox/>}
                </div>
              </div>
            )
        }
    }

export default App;
```

2. Navigation.js (Where the button is clicked but are not being defined anywhere so cannot find the page to take me to the forms.)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dropdown from "../components//pages/dropdowns/dropdowns"; 
import hamburger from "../images/menu.svg"


class Navigation extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isExpanded: false
        };
    }

    handleToggle(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          isExpanded: !prevState.isExpanded, // negate the previous expanded state
        }));
      }


    render() {

        const { isExpanded } = this.state;

      return (
          <Router>
              <div className="NavbarContainer">
                  <div className="mobilecontainer LeftNav">
                      <h2 className="BrandName LeftNav mobileboxmenu inline FarRight">Kommonplaces</h2>
                      <div className="hamburger inlinev" >
                          <img 
                            onClick={e => this.handleToggle(e)}
                            alt="menubtn" 
                            src={hamburger}
                          />
                      </div>
                  </div>


                  <ul className={`NavBar collapsed ${isExpanded ? "is-expanded" : ""}`}>
                        <Dropdown/>    
                        <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Host Your Space</Link></li>
                        <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">About Us</Link></li>
                        <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Contact Us</Link></li>
                        <div className="btnflexright">
                        <button
                            className={"controller " + (this.state.isLoginOpen
                            ? "selected-controller"
                            : "")}
                            onClick={this
                            .props
                            .showLoginBox}>
                            Login
                        </button>
                        
                        <button
                            className={"controller " + (this.state.isRegisterOpen
                            ? "selected-controller"
                            : "")}
                            onClick={this
                            .props
                            .showRegisterBox}>
                            Sign up
                        </button>
                        </div>
                  </ul>
               </div>
         </Router>
      );
    }
}

  export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a couple things:

1. add some couple methods to your `App` component to set the state.
2. import and render the `Navigation` component in your `App` component (so you can pass your methods in as functions. you could use the Context API but it's more complicated...)
3. pass those methods as functions to your `Navigation` component (and pass the state in as props if you need them too)
4. call the methods through the props of your `Navigation` component

In your `App` component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import RegisterBox from '../Forms/Register'
import LoginBox from '../Forms/Login'

import Navigation from './Navigation'


// This is the page for form to live on
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoginOpen: true,
      isRegisterOpen: false
    };
  }

  /*
   * 1. add these two methods here to modify the state of `App`
   */
  showLoginBox() {
    this.setState({ isLoginOpen: true });
  }

  showRegisterBox() {
    this.setState({ isRegisterOpen: true });
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="root-container">
            {
              /* 2. render the `Navigation` component in `App` */
              /* 3. pass your methods in as function props to `Navigation` */
            }
            <Navigation 
              isLoginOpen={this.state.isLoginOpen}
              isRegisterOpen={this.state.isRegisterOpen}
              showLoginBox={this.showLoginBox.bind(this)} 
              showRegisterBox={this.showRegisterBox.bind(this)}
            />
            {this.state.isLoginOpen && <LoginBox/>}
            {this.state.isRegisterOpen && <RegisterBox/>}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now you can call those methods from your `Navigation` component...

```js
{ /* 4. call the prop functions in `Navigation` component */ }
<button
    className={"controller " + (this.props.isLoginOpen ? "selected-controller" : "")}
    onClick={this.props.showLoginBox}>
    Login
</button>

<button
    className={"controller " + (this.props.isRegisterOpen ? "selected-controller" : "")}
    onClick={this.props.showRegisterBox}>
    Sign up
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you @khuynh for explain step by step that what talking about this helps out a lot for my ADHD brain.

Comment: I have followed the step's that you have instructed but still don't worked

Comment: can you elaborate what problems are you still running into or what errors you are getting? @bpdg

Comment: When you mean to pass it methods in as functions what do you mean by that? Please explain

Comment: That's the problem I don't see any error in the console that what not understand why their no error but when I click the buttons none thing happens. When I click the button theirs no response happening in the console.

Comment: In our example, we are passing in the `showLoginBox` and `showRegisterBox` methods in `App` to our `Navigation` component as props. That way we can call them when we press the button in our `Navigation` component. To debug this, why not try adding a `console.log` statement inside the `showLoginBox` function. When you click it, you should see it in the console.

Comment: Here a video view https://www.loom.com/share/e2e02859cc7f4d3c9f26494b02f999d0

Comment: I have this inside a different files called MainSreen.js that where the form is going to live but when I add the `console.log` I don't see it anything.

Comment: In your `Home.js`, you need to render `<App />` instead of `<Navigation />`. Currently, you render `<Navigation />` with no props at all. @bpdg

Comment: Now, I understand now so you want me to run just app inside home.js and run navbar inside of <App /> this what I have so far https://gyazo.com/ffa0831a3f2e25de3a6ea8b919213b69

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206035/discussion-between-khuynh-and-bpdg).